# Shipment and deploy artifacts for boxfuse

Tags: cloudcaptain

If a software company wants to develop a piece of software and deliver a boxfuse-enabled component to the customer, so that he can deploy to AWS on their own, can I ask how this is best done?

I want to avoid shipping a jar file to the customer and force him to build from that jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You share a Boxfuse account with your customer. Preferably make it their Boxfuse account as it will be associated with their AWS account.

You can then use their account to fuse and push Boxfuse images to the Boxfuse Vault. Your customer can then run them using `boxfuse run`.